# Reproduce part of a hash

Tags: hash

I know very little about hashes, but I was wondering if I know the first 20 digits of what got hashed and the first 8 digits of the hash, is there any way to figure out the entire hash?

For example:
This is what is getting hashed using SHA256:
G3f3xfxQCG4f438e18e3f7d0ff5fbb42d0e233b331829cc0e07df04255892b4c411ba78d6c98c5490bd6

I know "G3f3xfxQCG4f438e18e3"

and after it gets hashed it becomes:
ac5b8839772026fcdf1ca090afb333795f4a63d155e6224bf23b0fa2789e1204

I also know:
ac5b8839

Is there any way for me to be able to get the full hash?

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way for me to be able to get the full hash?

**No.**

You didn't name your hash function. So I'm assuming, you're talking about a regular *cryptographic* hash function, like SHA-256 for example. In your regular cryptographic hash you want what is called the ["Avalaunch Effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect). It means that if even one bit of the input is flipped, added or removed, then the hashed output is very, very different.

For completeness sake: Two other *non-cryptographic* hashes:

- **Checksums**
  If you don't care about attackers, then you might want do use a faster hash, that **isn't** a cryptographic hash. This is sometimes also called a "checksum". Like CRC-32 for example.
  There the emphasis is on detecting transmission errors and not malicious manipulation.
- **Similarity preserving hashes**
  If you actually **want** similarities to be preserved, then the last thing you want is the Avalanche Effect. For example if you have a large collection of files and want to sort them by similarity. Or if you have a virus sample and want to know if another file is somehow virus-y in that way as well. One hash that does this and preserves similarities is ["ssdeep"](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ssdeep). VirusTotal.com uses it on its results pages.